# How to select and count 3 elements in the same column in the same query and show them in three columns?

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, tweepy, apache-spark-sql

How can I write one query instead of these three?
Thanks for your answers!

```
    sqlCtx.sql("""Select count(*) as iPhone
    from yahoo
    where source like '%iphone%'
    """).show()

    sqlCtx.sql("""Select count(*) as Android
    from yahoo
    where source like '%android%'
    """).show()

    sqlCtx.sql("""Select count(*) as Web
    from yahoo
    where source like '%Web Client%'
    """).show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try condition for same and add 1 if exists else add 0, Here is Sample:-

```
sqlCtx.sql("""
       Select 
          sum(if source like '%iphone%', 1, 0) as Iphone,
          sum(if source like '%android%', 1, 0) as Android,
          sum(if source like '%Web Client%', 1, 0) as Web
       from yahoo
   """).show()
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i get an error.

ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 3))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-f73fa3d62f2d> in <module>()
      5           sum(if source like '%Web Client%', 1, 0) as Web
      6        from yahoo
----> 7    """).show()

Comment: what is 5,6,7? looks some problem in testing